# Debian disk full, How to increase size?

Tags: linux, debian, web-server

I have a small web server running Debian 7. If I run command `df -h`, I can see that I have `/dev/mapper/deb--webxxx-root/` allmost full, 17 megabytes of free space.

How can I allocate more free space? `/dev/mapper/deb--webxxx-home/` has 130 gigabytes of free space. Can I some how move some of that free space to another mapper? Debian is a virtual machine so I could add more disk space quite easily too, but how?

I 'am newbaby on these debian server things...

pvdisplay:

```
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               deb-web138
  PV Size               159,76 GiB / not usable 2,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              40898
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          40898
  PV UUID               3rsJgY-I7KJ-Mv7H-xQ3Z-jNGn-z4bE-eKTUmH
```

Vgdisplay

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               deb-web138
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                6
  Open LV               6
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               159,76 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              40898
  Alloc PE / Size       40898 / 159,76 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               90CrJD-xtBB-DaZB-UD1R-Lzxj-90w2-kZROya
```

lvdisplay

```
  LV Path                /dev/deb-web138/tmp
  LV Name                tmp
  VG Name                deb-web138
  LV UUID                IKNzaW-t55g-FiIK-lP8L-3OFe-Lg8z-hg910U
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time deb-web138, 2014-12-15 16:18:55 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                380,00 MiB
  Current LE             95
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:4
```

lvscan

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/deb-web138/root' [332,00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/deb-web138/usr' [8,38 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/deb-web138/var' [2,79 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/deb-web138/swap_1' [4,00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/deb-web138/tmp' [380,00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/deb-web138/home' [143,89 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: Pls attach to your post output of the following commands: `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, `lvdisplay`

Comment: No idea what those are, but just edited results of those...

Comment: It is strange that `lvdisplay` shows only one logical volume. Pls attach output of `lvcan` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are running a virtual machine and adding new disk is easy task, I would suggest you to add a new virtual disk instead of shrinking /home because it might be difficult for you.

Depends on your VM host, add a new virtual disk to your VM.

Then, check the device name for your new disk by:

```
# fdisk -l
```

You will get something similar to below:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 70.9 GB, 70866960384 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8615 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Next, you need to either partition your disk or simply make use of whole disk:

To partition your disk (assume you have disk with label /dev/sdb) added:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb
Command (m for help): n
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4): 1
First cylinder (1-8615, default 1): 1
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (1-8615, default 8615):
Using default value 8615
```

Next, you need to format the disk the become a Physical Volume of LVM:

```
# pvcreate /dev/sdb1
```

From your information, you have a volume group **deb-web138**. So you can add new space by:

```
# vgextend deb-web138 /dev/sdb1
```

You will now have new space added to volume group, resize your logical volume *root* by 70G for example:

```
# lvresize -L+70G /dev/deb-web138/root
# resize2fs /dev/deb-web138/root
```

When the resizing operation completes, you will have new free space and can be checked by the command:

```
# df -h
```

When you need to add new space again, you can add new virtual disk and follow the procedure as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to unmount `/home` partition which you are going to shrink and get `root` access.
Now your `/dev/deb-web138/home` has 143G. For example we want to leave it with 100G and add 43G to `/dev/deb-web138/root`
 1. Reduce `/dev/deb-web138/home`
`lvreduce -L 100g -r /dev/deb-web138/home`
 2. Add freed space to `/dev/deb-web138/root`
`lvextend -L +43G /dev/deb-web138/root`
Thats it, just mount your `/home` back. Note that `-r` arg implies `resize2fs` so you don't need to run it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

First you have to reduce size of  `/home`. 
Unmount `/home` parition - on-line shrinking is not supported. Then change filesystems size with

```
root@localhost # resize2fs /dev/mapper/deb--webxxx-home <new_size>
```

Then reduce LogicalVolume size with

```
root@localhost # lvresize -L <new_size> /dev/mapper/deb--webxxx-home
```

Now it's time to resize that Logical Volume for `/root` with

```
root@localhost # lvresize -L +<free_space> /dev/mapper/deb--webxxx-root
```

After that, you have to resize filesystem with resize2fs

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/deb--webxxx-root
```

Note: this is general way for resizing partitions based on Logical Volumes